# Отправка Eth выдает ошибку при использовании wb3-php библиотеки

Tags: php

Пытаюсь создать транзакцию через свой сайт. Но почему-то выдаёт ошибку

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Web3\\Exceptions\\ErrorException: invalid json request in /var/www/****/data/vendor/web3-php/web3/src/Transporters/Http.php:59
```

Код:

```
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\ValueObjects\{Transaction, Wei};

$from = '0x98d90***E02f5f0D0e*****Dbe7b0a810db'; 
$to = '0x1ABF4***9c4bf82e185E****aB9C5C0b7c6'; 

$provider='https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/1aa3d93b42184*******8cecd1028'; //testnet bsc

$web3 = new Web3($provider);

$balance_eth = $web3->eth()->getBalance($from)->toEth(); 
$value =  Wei::fromEth('100000000000');
$transaction = Transaction::between($from, $to)->withValue($value);

$web3->eth()->sendTransaction($transaction);
```

Может у кого-то было?

Comment: Для начала, не плохо было быть ссылку на это API. Мне повезло, т.к. в гугле меня не забанили и я [всё-таки нашёл](https://github.com/web3-php/web3). Во-вторых, посмотрите, что приходит в ответе, до обработки данных. Для этого можно, например, вывести в файл переменную `$contents` [на строке 54 в классе Http](https://github.com/web3-php/web3/blob/master/src/Transporters/Http.php#L54), а дальше разбираться

Comment: файлик сделал в него записалось следующее {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid json request"}}

Comment: [Вот тут рассматривается](https://community.infura.io/t/web3-js-1-0-0-beta-37-call-raises-code-32600-message-invalid-json-request/583) максимально близкая к вашей проблема. Насколько я могу понять, суть в том, что разные версии библитеки Web3 по разному формирует данные для передачи по API. Проблема не в валидности JSON, с точки зрения синтаксиса, а в структуре